# Rotate Certain QWidgets in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I need to rotate certain elements of the UI (not all). I have tried a couple of things already and none of them have provided the solution I require.

I attempted to use the QGraphicsProxyWidget and Graphics View, this worked well for if I wanted to rotate the entire UI, but provided no way to rotate only certain elements.

I attempted to promote the widget to a custom class that overrides the paintEvent. I am unable to get this way to work though. The following is my current code

```
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>    

class QRotateButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QRotateButton (QWidget *parent = 0) {}

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override {
        if (isDrawing)
            return QRotateButton::paintEvent(event);

        isDrawing = true;
        QPixmap buttonPixmap = grab();
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.rotate(90);
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, height(), width(), buttonPixmap);
        isDrawing = false;
    }
private:
    bool isDrawing = false;
};
```

This returns the following errors

```
QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected
Segmentation fault
```

Thanks in advance

**Update**

Following the comments below I changed the code to call `QPushButton::paintEvent(Event)` instead of `QRotateButton::paintEvent(Event)`

The application does now open, where as it didn't before. But unfortunately no button is shown. Whenever the paintEvent gets invoked now, the following error messages appear in the console:

```
QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::rotate: Painter not active
```

Comment: As for the `Recursive repaint detected` - do not use `QRotateButton::paintEvent(event);`, call `QPushButton::paintEvent(event);`. You will run into recursion when `isDrawing` is true. Otherwise, what is this method supposed to do? Why do you want to call the base method only when `isDrawing` is true?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis The idea of the isDrawing variable is because "grab()" calls paintEvent again. If I don't have that there, the method loops until it hits a segmentation fault. I want to call the base method so that I can get the pixmap of the button and then I can rotate it

Comment: How does in invoke the `paintEvent` if you don't pass the event to it? And also, does fixing the call to the base class solve it?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis I believe that `grab()` creates a new event due to it requiring the image to be drawn in order to fetch a pixmap of it. But I am unsure since this is a function of the QPushButton and not one of mine. I have updated the main question with the new issue seen after fixing the call to the base class. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with this further, I managed to figure it out.

```
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>

class QRotateButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:    
    QRotateButton (QWidget *) {        
        //Set variables to defaults
        _isDrawing = false;
        _recursiveCounter = 0;
        _recursiveMax = 1;
        _rotationSetting = 0;
        _rotationAngle = 0;
        _rotationX = 0;
        _rotationY = 0;
        _rotationWidth = 0;
        _rotationHeight = 0;
    }

    /* Set rotation setting */
    void SetRotation(int setting) {
        //Set rotation setting
        _rotationSetting = setting;

        //Call paintEvent
        this->update();
    }


protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override {        
        //If its drawing then it just wants to do the normal paintEvent
        if (_isDrawing)
        {
            QPushButton::paintEvent(event);
            return;
        }       

        //Setup the variables depending on setting
        setupRotationVariables();       

        //Setup painter and rotate to angle
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.rotate(_rotationAngle);

        //Without this here, this function is called over and over,
        //this stops that whilst maintaing the rotated image we want
        if (_recursiveCounter > 0 && _requiresRotation)
        {
            _recursiveCounter--;
            painter.drawPixmap(_rotationX, _rotationY, _drawing.width(), _drawing.height(), _drawing);            
            return;
        }


        //When rotating 90/270 degrees, we resize the image so that we don't stretch the image
        //This is not required when flipping the image
        if (_requiresRotation)                    
            resize(_rotationWidth, _rotationHeight);



        //Get the button image, this will call this function so we set _isDrawing to true whilst it's going on so meaning that it's does the base method and returns
        _isDrawing = true;
        _drawing = grab();
        _isDrawing = false;

        //Now we have the image, if rotation is being done resize the widget back to it's previous measurements
        if (_requiresRotation)                   
            resize(_rotationHeight, _rotationWidth);

        //Draw the image to the picture
        painter.drawPixmap(_rotationX, _rotationY, _drawing.width(), _drawing.height(), _drawing);

        //Depending on if this has rotated or not, setup the catch the tailend of the rotation event
        if (_requiresRotation)
            _recursiveCounter = _recursiveMax;
        else
            _recursiveCounter = 0;
    }

private:
    /* Stops Recursive resizing when resizing is required */
    int _recursiveCounter;
    int _recursiveMax;

    /* If the widget is currently drawing, stops certain recursive calls */
    bool _isDrawing;    

    /* If the widget needs to rotated instead of flipped */
    bool _requiresRotation;

    /* Contains image of previous render of button, for use in recursive calls */
    QPixmap _drawing;

    /* Rotation Setting (0-3) defines rotation type. This is used since rotations should only be multiples of 90 */
    int _rotationSetting;

    /* Variables after rotation */
    int _rotationAngle;
    int _rotationX;
    int _rotationY;
    int _rotationWidth;
    int _rotationHeight;

    /* Fetch variables based on Rotation Setting */
    void setupRotationVariables () {
        //Figure out what rotation is required
        switch (_rotationSetting)
        {
        case 0: //Up side up
            _rotationAngle = 0;
            _rotationWidth = width();
            _rotationHeight = height();
            _rotationX = 0;
            _rotationY = 0;
            _requiresRotation = false;
            break;
        case 1: //Right side up
            _rotationAngle = 90;
            _rotationWidth = height();
            _rotationHeight = width();
            _rotationX = 0;
            _rotationY = -width();
            _requiresRotation = true;
            break;
        case 2: //Down side up
            _rotationAngle = 180;
            _rotationWidth = width();
            _rotationHeight = height();
            _rotationX = -width();
            _rotationY = -height();
            _requiresRotation = false;
            break;
        case 3: //Left side up
            _rotationAngle = 270;
            _rotationWidth = height();
            _rotationHeight = width();
            _rotationX = -height();
            _rotationY = 0;
            _requiresRotation = true;
            break;
        default:
            printf("INVALID ROTATION\n");
            break;
        }
    }

};
```

### Note

This will still throw `QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected` every time paintEvent is called, but we expect this and it is handled in code. Whilst I would prefer it not show, I am unable to figure out any way to stop it.